# Using multiple radio boxes with same name in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery for the first time and I would like to get a value from one of my checkboxes with the same name.

My code is:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a#process_input').bind('click', function() {
    $(":checked").each(function() {
      $.getJSON('/management/avaliable_numbers', {
        num_of_numbers: $('input[name="num_of_numbers"]').val(),
      }, function(data) {
        $("#result").html(data.result);
      })
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<div class='container'>
  <form>
    <div>
      <input type="radio" name="num_of_numbers" value="10"> 10
      <input type="radio" name="num_of_numbers" value="100"> 100
      <input type="radio" name="num_of_numbers" value="1000"> 1000
      <a href='#' id=process_input>
        <button type="button" class="btn">Choose</button>
      </a>
    </div>
    <p id=result></p>
</div>
```

It is a ready-to-go code from jquery+flask tutorial with some mashup from resources I found on the internet. As you may expect it is not working as I expect it to be.
No matter which option I pick (even if I don't pick any) that script sends 10 to the *avaliable_numbers* function.

I am looking for an explanation how to implement that correctly so when I don't check any on the boxes it passes nothing to the function either way it passes a respective value.

Thank you in advance for any advises.

Comment: You are looping over the checked inputs: `$(":checked").each(function() {` .  `this` will be the radio button.  Just get the `this.value`.

Comment: Also use `.on` instead of `.bind` as the latter has been deprecated

Comment: And if you are just wanting to do the json call on the checked val - instead of an each loop, just do `$('input[name="num_of_numbers:checked"]').val()` in your `getJson` (your each loop at the moment will loop through all checked inputs (not just the one you want)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I would make a few changes to your script (comments in code explaining what and why)

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('a#process_input').on('click', function(e) { // change bind to on as bind is deprectaed in jquery v3
                                                     // also pass the event back into the function

        e.preventDefault(); // stops the form submitting - you don't want it to reload the page - removes the need for returning false at the end

        if ($('input[name="num_of_numbers"]:checked').length) { // only do the following if there is something checked

          // remove each loop - not needed as you only want to pass the checked value to the json
          $.getJSON('/management/avaliable_numbers', {
            num_of_numbers: $('input[name="num_of_numbers"]:checked').val(), // just pass through the checked value
          }, function(data) {
            $("#result").html(data.result);
          });

        } else {
            $("#result").html('error message - please check a radio'); // nothing checked - might want an error message 
        }


      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<div class='container'>
  <form>
    <div>
      <input type="radio" name="num_of_numbers" value="10"> 10
      <input type="radio" name="num_of_numbers" value="100"> 100
      <input type="radio" name="num_of_numbers" value="1000"> 1000
      <a href='#' id=process_input>
        <button type="button" class="btn">Choose</button>
      </a>
    </div>
  </form>             <!-- add missing form closing tag -->
  <p id=result></p>
</div>
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you Pete, you're the saviour of my day :)

Comment: @hikamare see edit - just seen you wanted it only when something was checked

Answer (score 0):

This might be an easier way to make the API call that you are trying. It basically hinges on the fact that a named input is available directly on the parent form element.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Get ref to the form element
  var form = $('form')[0];
  
  // Register click handler on the button
  $('a#process_input').on('click', function() {
    // The current value will be available as form.num_of_numbers.value
    var num_of_numbers = form.num_of_numbers.value;
    if(!num_of_numbers){
      // No value selected
      return;
    }
    //When the click happens, pass the current selected value to the API call
    $.getJSON('/management/avaliable_numbers', {
        num_of_numbers: num_of_numbers,
      },
      function(data) {
        // Update result div
        $("#result").html(data.result);
      })
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='container'>
  <form>
    <div>
      <input type="radio" name="num_of_numbers" value="10"> 10
      <input type="radio" name="num_of_numbers" value="100"> 100
      <input type="radio" name="num_of_numbers" value="1000"> 1000
      <a href='#' id=process_input>
        <button type="button" class="btn">Choose</button>
      </a>
    </div>
  </form>
  <p id=result></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// fake out getJSON for StackOverflow
jQuery.getJSON = function (url, options, callback) {
  callback({ result: 'weeee: '+ options.num_of_numbers });
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  // cache the element lookup
  var $numOfNumbers = $('.num-of-numbers');
  
  $('#process_input').on('click', function(e) {
    // preventDefault rather than returning false
    // as false does more than just preventing default
    e.preventDefault();
    
    // check if any of the radio buttons are checked
    if ($numOfNumbers.filter(':checked').length) {
      $.getJSON('/management/avaliable_numbers', {
                        // get the value of the checked radio
        num_of_numbers: $numOfNumbers.filter(':checked').val(),
      }, function(data) {
        $("#result").html(data.result);
      })
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <form>
    <div>
      <input type="radio" name="num_of_numbers" value="10" class="num-of-numbers"> 10
      <input type="radio" name="num_of_numbers" value="100" class="num-of-numbers"> 100
      <input type="radio" name="num_of_numbers" value="1000" class="num-of-numbers"> 1000

      <a href="#" id="process_input">
        <button type="button" class="btn">Choose</button>
      </a>
    </div>
    <p id="result"></p>
</div>
```